# Rails language name using I18n locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I want to match the locale code to the specific language name. Is there any build in function in I18n/rails which would return the language name to the corresponding locales. Is installing a gem is the only way?

Comment: Are you asking for a method that maps `"en"` to `"English"`, `"fr"` to `"French"`, and so on?

Comment: 5 seconds on google, and I found: https://github.com/grosser/i18n_data -- does that solve your problem?

Comment: @TomLord Yes, thats the mapping I reuiqired. This is an additional gem to solve the problem. I want to know is there any other alternative without an extra gem.

Comment: `I18n` only provides the framework, the content has to be provided by the framework's consumer. Rails for example adds [active_model/locale/en.yml](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml) and [active_support/locale/en.yml](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml). Neither of these contain language names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems there is no method for this in I18n.
If you just need current language name, you can easily include it in corresponding locale file:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  language_name: "English"
```

And get it as usual: `I18n.t('language_name')` or `I18n.t('language_name', locale: :en)`.

For general purposes you could use: https://github.com/hexorx/countries or initialize your own mapping as a ruby hash: `{ en: 'English', ... }`.

Comment: @Stefan, in that case you'd have to have the de.yml with language_name: "German" key and subsequently all the locale yamls for all the languages you are interested in. That's why (for me personally) it's not an ideal solution (unless you already have all the locale yamls)

Comment: Shouldn't `de.yml` have German content, i.e. `language_name: "Deutsch"`?

Comment: @Stefan, yes, if it's used anywhere in a view as a text then it should have the translated string (Deutsch). If it's used for some other purpose (which kinda goes against the idea of what the locale yamls are, at least primarily, for) then it doesn't matter. It's a hacky solution to the problem at hand. It's an interesting one, but not something I personally would use (even though it definitely works).

Comment: Maybe the locale files should not just contain their own language name, but all language names, i.e. a file `languages.en.yml` with `en: { languages: { en: 'English', de: 'German' } }` and another file `languages.de.yml` with `de: { languages: { en: 'Englisch', de: 'Deutsch' } }` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Without installing an additional gem, you could make your own key/value pairs (either store it in a json file or store it to DB) and then lookup key eg "de" and read the value (in this case, "German"). It requires a bit of manual work (or setup a rake task or something to build it for you in appropriate format from some info source) but you aren't dependent on an additional gem in that case (which, without going thoroughly through the code, might have a far greater impact on your app performance/memory wise than your custom implementation for your specific need for all you know).

I am not aware of any rails built in functions that would return the entire language name, though. You can return the language abbreviation (eg for use in html lang attribute), but I think it stops there as far as the built in functions are concerned).

Comment: @Charles, I agree storing in DB is not necessarily the best solution, it depends if you already have a table in which it would make sense to include another column (eg you already have a table with info regarding every country and would just add locale). My point was that you have to store it somewhere. Storing it in locale yamls themselves is a valid and neat solution if you have yamls for each language already, otherwise I personally would prefer to store it in a json file (so you have everything in one place and only need to generate one additional file instead of a couple dozen files) :)

Comment: @I.varga I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look the following post in [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rails-i18n/cFbxHcOVfnA) ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/henrik/276191)). I hope there is no default support for the required conversion in rails.